# Event grid function URL from powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I have an event grid triggered function app. I am using the below code to get function URL.

```
function Get-Function-Key {
    return (Invoke-AzResourceAction `
            -Action listKeys `
            -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/' `
            -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
            -ResourceName "$FuncAppName/$FuncName" `
            -Force).default
}

$functionKey = Get-Function-Key -FuncAppName $FuncAppName -FuncName $FuncName `
                -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroup

$apiUrl = "https://$FuncAppName.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid?functionName=$FuncName&code=$functionKey"
```

I noticed the function URL uses masterkey instead of function key. Is there any command in powershell to get master key of the function URL.

Comment: Your function does not have a `param` block, yet you call it using parameters??

Comment: I am new to powershell scripting. I currently exploring , I will change it later as per standards.By the way those parameters are set  through azure devops release pipeline. I think we set it at script parameters section in azure powershell task.

Comment: I have no experience in azure tasks, but if a function should use parameters, you need to define them as the first line in the function: `param([string]$FuncAppName, [string]$FuncName, [string]$ResourceGroup)`

Comment: Any update this issue? If it is helpful, please accept it as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I test your commands on my side, it returns the function key of the EventGridTrigger in  the function app.

So if you want to get the master key, just use the command below.

```
function Get-Function-Key {
 param([string]$FuncAppName,[string]$ResourceGroup)
    return (Invoke-AzResourceAction `
            -Action listKeys `
            -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/sites/host/default' `
            -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
            -ResourceName "$FuncAppName" `
            -Force).masterKey
}
```